# session distributable EAP it's not working

Tags: java, jboss-eap-7

I have one master and two slave into domain modes, using and httpsession and distributable into web.xml but the session is not shaing into domains, Im access one node and work, but when access the other node the session is not sharing.

the configuration is the following 
1 master
2 slaves(slave1, slave2)
1 server group (demo)
2 nodes (node11 server slave1, node21 server slave2 )

When access node 11 and make the login, and then chage to node21 the session is not persisted, and the result is null.
and try with another app for session but have the same issue
jboss eap is 7.2 and jdk is open jdk 1.8

I try using two different application of session sharing, and none of  work.
Im try the same on on server on different ports and the session was shared

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<distributable/>` tag in your `web.xml`. You may need to enable session replication on your JBoss domain server as well. Refer https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277766 for more details.

You should also read JBoss EAP documentation on this [Configuring high availbility](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/configuring_high_availability)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by master vs slave modes.  This is not a concept on which EAP clustering relies.
Additionally, domain mode is about management, not about clustering.  These are completely orthogonal concepts.
From a management perspective, servers within a given server-group share the same configuration.  Generally, if the server-group is configured to use an "ha" profile (which defines a JGroups subsystem which is the starting point for cluster configuration), and multicast is allowed on your network, servers should form a cluster out-of-the-box.

If this is not happening, look to your server logs to figure out what is happening, and to the docs for configuring JGroups discovery w/out multicast.